# Approving or disapproving requests in one flutter app from another flutter app

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, authentication

So, I have created two applications, user and admin, using flutter. And both of them are in a single firebase project.

The Applications are investment-related. What I want to do is, Suppose a user sends an investment request from the user app. Another user in the admin app should be able to approve or disapprove the request and then the request status should be visible in the user app. Is there any way to do it?

What I tried: I created a new field in Firebase Realtime Database named `Request Status`. Then I passed a String `Approved` into it through the Admin app but it didn't work.

```dart
...
final investmentRequestsRef = database.child("Investment Requests");
...
void addData(String requestStatus) {
  investmentRequestRef.set({
    "Request Status": requestStatus,
  });
}
...
```

Code of `button` that updates the `status`:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  ...
  onPressed: () {
    addData("Approved");
  },
  ...
)
```

[What happens in realtime database when I do the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKJv5.png)

Comment: Can you add more details like what is the problem when you're saying it's not working? LIke is the database field not updating or is the second app not getting access to the database?

Comment: The String 'Approved or disapproved' gets entered in the realtime database under the UID of the account I'm using for the admin app instead of being entered under the UID of the account of the user that sent the investment request from the user app.

Comment: The method seems alright and should work as well. When the user makes an investment request you initialize the `status` field with `disapproved` or `pending`. When the admin approves the request from the admin app you update the `status` field to `approved`. You can keep checking/listening to the value in the client app and when it changes to `approved` you show it.

Comment: Yes, the method is right but the problem here is, as I mentioned, that it doesn't get entered underneath the UID of the user that sent the request but instead gets entered out of it.

Comment: Can you add the code where you are setting the `status` then?

Comment: Sure. I have edited my question post with three screenshots that might help you in understanding my problem better.

Comment: Can you add the code for `investmentRequestsRef`? I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: Yes. I just added the code for investmentRequestRef.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this...

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("Investment Requests/${requestID}");

await ref.update({
  "Request Status": requestStatus,
});
```

This should work... I haven't seen your full code so I can't add anything else without more details about your code.

Use [this official link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/read-and-write) of FlutterFire for reference.

Comment: what should I specify as requestID so that it refers to UID of all the users?

Comment: You should replace `requestID` with the ID of that particular Investment Request. Can you clarify what you mean by "of all the users"? Do you want to set the status for all the requests at once?

Comment: What I mean is new requests are going to keep coming from different users, so it wont be possible to keep adding or changing UID in the code every time right. So what can I do instead of writing the UID directly so that it refers to the UID of the person that sent the request.

Comment: No, you won't have to change the code to point to a particular ID. The way it should work is... You show all the requests in the admin app. When the admin taps on any request... you have to get its ID. That's a simple way of doing it. I don't know the structure and flow of your app so that's all I can say.

Comment: Let's see what I can do. Anyways, Thank you so much for your help.